# LatinIME dictionary

Tags: android

I want to add Czech dictionary to LatinIME (it is only missing part, UI and keyboard are already here).
I found source of LatinIME in source of android itself. There is a sample.xml file which show correct structure for creating dictionaries, but there is a point I got stuck. What do I have to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have starting reading about this about a week ago.
I think you should read code from [this link](http://code.google.com/p/android-greek-ime/). He did something similiar but in Greek.

Hope it's useful.

Comment: looks like it is only keyboard, can't find dictionary

Comment: check http://code.google.com/p/android-greek-ime/source/browse/trunk/src/net/bitquill/inputmethod/greek/BinaryDictionary.java he loads a dict in the static block using System.loadLibrary("greekim");

Comment: huh..feeling like real stupid, but can you explain more? In which file is dictionary specified? I didn't found any dict/xml file. Does it mean it is typed in some java file?

Comment: The dictionary is here: http://code.google.com/p/android-greek-ime/source/browse/trunk/#trunk/jni

Answer (score 2):

This guy made a dutch dictionary, and it's simple to understand.

It's what you're looking for: 
http://blog.cone.be/2010/08/20/creating-dutch-dictionary-for-android/

I'm trying to build one for Serbian. Good luck.

Comment: the link given is for Softkeyboard. We want it for LatinIME